# Preload image only after the full page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

I want to preload 5-6 images so that I can display them when the user scrolls down (facebook-like-auto-load-on-scroll). So when the user scrolls down, the images are displayed without further loading. I used the following CSS code earlier:

```
img.not-load
{
 display:none;
}
```

So, when using jQuery, I made them visible, they appeared without loading. But the problem is that, the page-loading time increased. I want to use jQuery to load the images **ONLY AFTER** the full page was loaded. I tried using jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` but it worked almost in the same manner, that is loading the required images WHILE the page is loading. I hope you understand my problem. I am a beginner in jQuery and need some clue to proceed further. Your assistance is appreciated in advance...

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: try JQUERY LAZY LOAD - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: I think this topic discusses the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [**`$(window).on('load')`**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event instead of the `$(document).ready()` like you attempted.

This would wait for **all** elements on the page to load before triggering.

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
   // Perform tasks after everything has loaded.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is lazyload
remake your img tags like this

```
 <img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

and add javascript

```
  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    ...
    <script>
        $(function() {
            ... pre-load your images here ...
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```